# Refactoring validator system

Tags: java, spring, interface

I've validator system that validates input data before saving to DB.
So let's say I want to create new user.
We are at the service class:

```
package main.user;

import main.entity.User;
import main.user.validator.attributesvalidators.UserAttributesValidator;
import main.user.validator.availabilityvalidators.UserAvailabilityValidator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserCrudActivitiesService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserCrudActivitiesService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }


    public List<String> createUser(User user) {
        UserAttributesValidator userAttributesValidator = new UserAttributesValidator();
        UserAvailabilityValidator userAvailabilityValidator = new UserAvailabilityValidator(userRepository);
        List<String> messages = userAttributesValidator.validate(user);
        messages.addAll(userAvailabilityValidator.check(user));
        if (messages.isEmpty()) {
            userRepository.save(user);
            //TODO passwordencoder
        }
        return messages;
    }

    public User updateUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

We've got two validators - first which will check whether attributes of user are fine and then whether some of attributes are free so we're sure that this user will be unique.

Validators structure:

[image]

In both we got same interface:
(for example interface for attributes)

```
package main.user.validator.attributesvalidators;

import main.entity.User;

public interface IUserAttributesValidator {

    String validate(User user);
}
```

Then we got somehing which is called (again for attrubutes) **UserAttributesValidator**
It's the class which contain all others validators and inside of it's constructor we create list of all validators so we can loop through all in one stream.

```
package main.user.validator.attributesvalidators;

import main.entity.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserAttributesValidator {

    final private List<IUserAttributesValidator> validators;

    public UserAttributesValidator() {
        validators = new ArrayList<>();
        validators.add(new UserEmailValidator());
        validators.add(new UserFirstNameValidator());
        validators.add(new UserLastNameValidator());
        validators.add(new UserPasswordValidator());
        validators.add(new UserPhoneValidator());
        validators.add(new UsernameValidator());
    }

    public List<String> validate(User user) {
        return validators.stream()
                .map(e -> e.validate(user))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

We get list as an output and it's fine. Same thing is done for **AvailabilityValidator**

One on validator for example:

```
package main.user.validator.attributesvalidators;

import main.entity.User;

public class UsernameValidator implements IUserAttributesValidator {

    public static final int NAME_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 30;
    public static final int NAME_MINIMUM_LENGTH = 3;
    public static final String NAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9]+";

    @Override
    public String validate(User user) {
        String attribute = user.getUsername();
        if (attribute.length() > NAME_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) {
            return "username is too long";
        } else if (attribute.length() < NAME_MINIMUM_LENGTH) {
            return "username is too short";
        } else if (!attribute.matches(NAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER_REGEX)) {
            return "username contains illegal character";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, my concern is.... I think that this is bad design. I mean, I create interface IUserAttributesValidator, then I create class that contain all others validators that has also method which is name the same as the method in interface. I wonder whether I can merge these two into one? Is it possible? Is there any possibility to improve this code?
Another my thought is that both (availability and attributes checker) has the same interface with the same method but different argument, but I don't know whether it is also possible to have only one interface for both.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, I have seen you are using `spring` in your system and my first thought was to use `javax.validation` package for validation that is often coupled with the framework. There is some specific reason to not use this already available package ?

Comment: @dariosicily not really, I did not know that something like that exists

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment below your question, java already covers your need of defining custom validators for your data before saving them in the database. The package coupled with the `spring` framework is the `javax.validation` package, so taking for example your custom validator code:

```
public class UsernameValidator implements IUserAttributesValidator {

    public static final int NAME_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 30;
    public static final int NAME_MINIMUM_LENGTH = 3;
    public static final String NAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9]+";

    @Override
    public String validate(User user) {
        String attribute = user.getUsername();
        if (attribute.length() > NAME_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) {
            return "username is too long";
        } else if (attribute.length() < NAME_MINIMUM_LENGTH) {
            return "username is too short";
        } else if (!attribute.matches(NAME_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER_REGEX)) {
            return "username contains illegal character";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can be replaced using the mechanism of annotations directly inside your `User` class in this way :

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class User {
    
    @Size(min=3, max=30, message="username length should be between 3 and 30 chars")
    //it seems me username should contain just these chars
    @Pattern(regexp="[A-Za-z0-9]+", message="username contains illegal characters") 
    private String username;
}
```

The same mechanism can be applied to the other fields of your `User` class when you need in the same way.

Comment: Oh, that's great how fast can we apply these validators here. I cannot find since when this is available. I'm using the newest SpringBoot, but since what version of Spring I can use it? Do you have such a knowledge?

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot check [SpringBoot validation guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) and `pom` associated for dependencies, for Spring probably you have to add manually the maven dependency.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure on what question you answered haha or I did not understand unfortunately. I mean, for sure it will be available for newest SpringBoot, but I'm wondering what spring version is needed for that

Comment: @makiz1234 For Spring, you have to add the maven dependency to the `pom' and rebuild the project.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I asked about the least version of spring which is needed to have this validation

Comment: Nevertheless I will stay with TorbenPutkonen, because I cannot catch these messages  if I use javax.validaation and send for example to front. With previous solution I could collect all error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the possibility of implementing this with tools provided by Spring framework... what you have there is quite close to being a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern so it is a well known and accepted design. What you would need to change to achieve that is to have the both individual validators and the composite validator implement the exact same interface. It makes sense to have the `IUserAttributesValidator` return a `List<String>` or `Collection<String>` as in your example the `UsernameValidator` might find more than one violation in the input and it would be convenient to return both length and charater set violations from the same invocation (although checking length and character set in the same validator does smell a bit like single responsibility violation).

Also, instead of returning a List you can pass a list as a parameter so that each validator can append their errors to an existing list instead of creating a new disposable list on every error.

```
iterface Validator<T> {
    void validate(T target, List<String> errors);
}
```

Comment: Could you make a gist for that solution? I'm wondering whether this solution is better or this with javax.validation which was provided by @dariosicily

Comment: Agree with everything, fyi an irrilevant typo in the code example.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you send a gist with sample. I understand the deisgn pattern, but I dont knwo what to do with this parametrized validator how should I use it.

Comment: What is more                                                                                                           1)why you say that that I should return length also, why do I need need?                       2) you said that I should return List<String> then that I should pass errors, you mean I should choose one from these?

Comment: hey, you there?